# javamail api not display mail message

Tags: java, email

I am usinfg Javamail Api to read gmail.

```
 Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
```

But the mail content which i want doesn't display.
output of content

```
CONTENT:javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@103e0e9
```

why content is like this. i want mail message not like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all bodyparts of multipart to get email text.

`mp.getBodyPart(0)` is probably not of `Content-Type: text/plain`

It might be an attachment.